# I can't format C# in vscode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I have tried putting JSON in settings and enable C# formatter in setting and it is still showing
`There is no formatter for C# files installed` what do I do also where do I put JSON code in settings JSON. I have installed C# extension and visual studio code version is 1.60.1

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO669.png)

[Enabled C# format in setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZ0Ph.png)

Comment: why post images of text, hard for others to search who have the same error message

Comment: i can't post image because i have just created this account @rioV8

Comment: why not post the text shown on the images, so we can search later for the content

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Code with the OmniSharp C# extension doesn't format C# code without a `.csproj` file. You can create a new project if you type `dotnet new console` in the terminal.